# Microsoft Outlook not deleting shared emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm using Office 365 and my administrator has setup a new account using Enable IMAP retrieval.

He is able to delete items from the inbox, but I'm not. He is using Outlook 2010.

And he used Smartermail on a VPS to setup the account, if that helps.

Q: What is keeping me from deleting items?

Comment: The first step to solving the issue would be to analyze the error message or behavior you see when you try to delete the email. Unfortunately, you didn’t include those details therefore the question is unanswerable.

Comment: The next thing you need to do is speak with your administrator. Do you support your own computer and software, or does your organization bear that responsibility? Have you contacted Microsoft support?

Comment: What do you mean by " shared emails"?

Answer (score 0):

This has been an issue since Outlook 2016 with IMAP accounts.

One fix that seems to work - In Account Settings, under the Advanced tab for the mail account, insert the word "Inbox" in the Root Folder field.

You may have go through the control panel applet (with Outlook closed) to access the advanced settings. See this link for details - [Advanced Settings missing from Outlook 365](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/advanced-settings-missing-from-outlook-365/03f4ae5f-8d3c-49a6-8da7-53cdcd272e3b)